# How to develop map based application in android

Tags: android, dictionary, location

I am trying to develop location based application in android. how to do it?

For example create a map for college or particular area.

Comment: This question is not very specific, but I guess what you want to do is to integrate with google maps so I recommend you to start reading the Android pages under https://developers.google.com/maps/
And also, do you have any experience in developing Android applications otherwise I would start with Android tutorials.

Comment: check this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wNlleczyPjs